# Click 2 buttons each other with function of html convertment by flag on off. Not toggleclass

Tags: jquery

I like to connect 2 buttons functions.

While box1 is opening, click box2 will close box1, and open box2.
While box2 is opening, click box1 will close box2, and open box1.

I like to keep html change of each buttons.

Its easy if I can use toggleclass to add and remove class for buttons, but it does not apply for these buttons that changes html by flag.

I tried to let them .click each other after checking their "length" or "visiality"(if there is length or visible of content, click other button each other), but this method cancels function each other.

html

```
<div class="wrapping">
<div class="buttontoggle1">
<div>box1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="content1">
green1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapping">
<div class="buttontoggle2">
<div>box2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="content2">
green2
    </div>

    </div>
```

css

```
.wrapping{
position:relative;float:left;margin-right:20px;}
    .content1,.content2{
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:green;
    }

    .buttontoggle1,.buttontoggle2{
    float:left;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
        margin-right:10px;
    }

    .close1,.close2{
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        border:white solid 2px;
    }

    .active{background-color:blue;}
```

Jquery

```
<!--box1 -->
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".content1").css("display","none");
  $(".buttontoggle1").on("click", function() {
    $(".content1").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(function(){
  var flg = "off";
  $('.buttontoggle1').on('click', function(){
    if(flg == "off"){
      $(this).html("<div class='close1'>clicked</div>");
      flg = "on";
    }else{
      $(this).html("<div>box1</div>");
      flg = "off";
    }
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(function () {
  $(".buttontoggle1").click(function (e) {
   if($(".content1").length>0)
      $(".content1").show();
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
});

   $(document).click(function() {
    if($(".close1").length>0)
     $(".buttontoggle1").click();
});
</script>


<!--box2 -->
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".content2").css("display","none");
  $(".buttontoggle2").on("click", function() {
    $(".content2").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(function(){
  var flg = "off";
  $('.buttontoggle2').on('click', function(){
    if(flg == "off"){
      $(this).html("<div class='close2'>clicked</div>");
      flg = "on";
    }else{
      $(this).html("<div>box2</div>");
      flg = "off";
    }
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(function () {
  $(".buttontoggle2").click(function (e) {
   if($(".content2").length>0)
      $(".content2").show();
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
});

   $(document).click(function() {
    if($(".close2").length>0)
     $(".buttontoggle2").click();
});
</script>




<!--This is what Im wondering how I can connect them -->

<script>
$(function(){
$('.buttontoggle2').on('click', function(){
if($(".close1").length>0)
$(".buttontoggle1").click();
});
});
</script>


<script>
$(function(){
$('.buttontoggle1').on('click', function(){
if($(".close2").length>0)
$(".buttontoggle2").click();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: post `html` and `css` code also. Do you mean accordian menu?

Comment: can you show HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code you want.

```
 <script>

  $(function(){
    $(".aaa").click(function() {
      if($(".bbbmenu").is(":visible")){
        $(".bbbmenu").hide();
        $(".aaamenu").show();
      }
    });

    $(".bbb").click(function() {
      if($(".aaamenu").is(":visible")){
        $(".aaamenu").hide();
        $(".bbbmenu").show();
      }
    });
  });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a shorter code by hiding all menus first and show the menu of current clicked button like below

```
<script>
      $(function(){
         $("button").click(function() {
            $("button menu").hide()
            $(this).show();
         });
      });
</script>
```

Note: this script is only applicable if your menu is relative of the button, since you did not show any html of it then I assumed that it was relative.